# Does anyone know why I am receiving this error when trying to convert a list to a dictionary?

Tags: python

```py
import re 
from collections import Counter
file = open("dialog.txt")

fileContents = file.read().lower() 
file.close()

cleanupText = re.compile("[^a-zA-Z]")
cleanText = re.sub(cleanupText," ",fileContents)

wordList = [cleanText.split()]

wordDictionary = {}

for item in wordList:
    if item in wordDictionary.keys():
        wordDictionary[item] += 1
    else:
        wordDictionary[item] = 1

print(wordDictionary)
```

This is what I have so far which just returns unhashable type list error, I am trying to count the occurrences of each unique word in the list and display that in a dictionary.  Does anyone know the exact cause of this error in this context? What can I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Please post your entire traceback, and, if possible, a sample of `dialog.txt`

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. `wordDictionary = Counter(wordList)`.

Comment: Where `wordList = re.findall("[a-z]+", fileContents)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
wordList = [cleanText.split()]
```

you get a list with one element, the element being a list returned by `cleanText.split()`. So it's something like `[['word1', 'word2']]`.

When you iterate over `wordList`, `item` points to the inner list. When you are trying to use a list as a dictionary key, you get this error. You can't use unhashable objects like lists as keys.

What you probably meant is to do this:

```
wordList = cleanText.split()
```

Comment: Thanks!  You're very kind, lol.